# How can i stop overlapping in this fizz buzz problem?

Tags: python

Hello can someone help me clean up my code? how can i replace the numbers with the words fizz, buzz of fizzbuzz instead of overlapping. And also the program wont let me divide num by itself

problem:

Write a program that prints the numbers from 1 to 100.

But for multiples of three print "Fizz" instead of the number and for the multiples of five print "Buzz".

For numbers which are multiples of both three and five print "FizzBuzz".

Instead of only printing "fizz", "buzz", and "fizzbuzz", add a fourth print statement: "prime". You should print this whenever you encounter a number that is prime (divisible only by itself and one).

```
"""

#fizz buzz homework


for num in range(100):
    print(num)
    if num % 3 == 0:
        print(num)
        print("fizz")
    if num % 5 == 0:
        print(num)
        print("buzz")
    if num % 3 == 0 and num % 5 == 0:
        print(num)
        print("fizzbuzz")
#    if num % num == 0:
#        print(num)
#        print("prime")
```

Comment: There are kind of two different questions here: 1) how do I implement fizzbuzz 2) how do I check to see if a number is prime.  These are both **very** common beginner coding exercises so I suggest doing a little google research, trying to apply it, and then if something is still giving you trouble you can ask a more focused question.

Comment: The very first Google result for "fizzbuzz python" is a perfectly reasonable implementation: https://www.w3resource.com/python-exercises/python-conditional-exercise-10.php

Comment: Thank you ! im still very new trying my best to learn.

Comment: You keep using `if`, think about what happens *when all three are true*.

Answer (score 1):

You got a few mistakes:

```
for num in range(100):
print(num) #This line is why all numbers are getting printed(you have no condition for them)
if num % 3 == 0:
    print(num) # you dont want this line because if num % 3 == 0 you only want to print 'fizz'
    print("fizz")
if num % 5 == 0:
    print(num) # Same for this line you want to only print 'buzz'
    print("buzz")
if num % 3 == 0 and num % 5 == 0: # Here you come to another problem beauce if num is dividable by 3 and by 5 then all 3 'if statements' will run. What you want to do is make sure that this is not the case before printing the others, you can do this by either changing your other 'if statements' to if num % 3 == 0 and num % 3 != 0 and vise versa
    print(num) # same here you want to only print 'fizzbuzz'
    print("fizzbuzz")
#if num % num == 0:
#    print(num)
#    print("prime")
```

Try this maybe:

```
for num in range(100):
    if num % 3 == 0 and num % 5 != 0:
        print("fizz")
    if num % 5 == 0 and num % 3 != 0:
        print("buzz")
    if num % 3 == 0 and num % 5 == 0: 
        print("fizzbuzz")
```

Comment: some more explaination about the changes done could be helpful to understand the mistakes

Comment: I appreciate the help.